# Detect if flowlistview has reached bottom

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to reload items into my flowlistview when it reached its bottom. therfore, I would need a function that fires once the end is reached.

I have this flowlistview set up:

```
  <flv:FlowListView  
            Grid.Column="1"
            FlowItemAppearing="listview_allAds_FlowItemAppearing"

            FlowColumnCount="2"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
            Refreshing="listview_allAds_Refreshing"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            FlowItemTapped="listview_allAds_FlowItemTapped"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            x:Name="listview_allAds" >

            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ContentView Padding="4,3,3,4"> <!--only way to set padding-->

                        <Frame BorderColor="#ffffff" 
                               HasShadow="True"        
                               Padding="0"
                               CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=5, iOS=5}">

                            <Grid ...>
                        </Frame>
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
```

I red that there is a lot you can do with "commands" but I am not sure how to do this.

Can you help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FlowItemAppearing`. The event you set in your code works well.

```
 async void listview_allAds_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {            

        if (e.ItemIndex ==  infos.Count/2)//2 is the FlowColumnCount of your FlowListView  
        {

            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Scrolled to the bottom", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: itemIndex will always be offset by the list.count. so either add one to the index or subtract on from count.